# how to match request line using regex?

Tags: python, regex

```
request line definition:
request_line := request_method + spaces + any number of other characters

eg: some valid request lines: 
  GET /user/1
  POST /users
  PUT ABC
  DELETE XYZ
```

So my question is how to match the request line? I have tried the following, but unfortunately it does not work.

```
re.compile('^[GET|POST|PUT|DELETE]\s+.+').match(request_line) # output None
```

Comment: also: maybe you forget `HEAD` method?

Comment: @sheh why exactly `HEAD`? there are a lot more http verbs but i would say that these four are the most used.

Comment: @Johny you are right) I just wanted to remind other methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `[GET|POST|PUT|DELETE]` Actually  matches a single character which may be anyone inside the charcter class `[]` . ie, it would be `G` or `E` or `T`....or `E`.

Your regex would be like this `(?:GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)` or `(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)`, so that it would mean the word `GET` or `POST` or `PUT` or `DELETE`. Put the words inside the non-capturing group `(?:)` if you don't want to capture. If you want to capture the method name then put them inside capturing groups`()`.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = """foo bar
... GET /user/1
... POST /users
... PUT ABC
... DELETE XYZ
... bar foo"""
>>> import re
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(?:GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)\s+.+', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
GET /user/1
POST /users
PUT ABC
DELETE XYZ
```

Answer (score 4):

you use `[]` to match for a specific set of characters
for example `[a-zA-Z]` would match all upper and lower case characters.

for your problem you have to use groups

try this

```
re.compile('^(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)\s+.+').match(request_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.compile('^(?:GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)\s+.*').match(request_line)
```

for any number of other characters we can use **.*** instead of **.+**